# Can not login site with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to log into a website with cURL but not working. 
I'm using this script.

But it does not work, it only redirects to the site home without logging

The form of this site is:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='origem' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='ultimo_endereco' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='forma_pagamento' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='video' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='url' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='evento' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='fotos' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='sessao' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='lista' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='perfil_longando' value=''>
<table align="center" width="25%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td><font face="" size="">Login:</font></td><td><input name="login_" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td><font face="" size="">Senha:</font></td><td><input name="senha_" type="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input name="logar" type="submit" value="Logar"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The script:

```
<?php
$username="user"; 
$password="123456"; 
$url="http://www.example.com/login.php"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata ="login_=$username&senha_=$password&logar=Logar";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch)
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the server is checking for the hidden inputs. Does it work if you add all of them to the post data?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this code here who can help

```
    <?php
    function login($url,$data){
        $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
        fclose($fp);
        $login = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($login);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($login);
        unset($login);    
    }                  

    function grab_page($site){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
        ob_start();
        return curl_exec ($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        curl_close ($ch);
    } login("http://www.example.com/login.php", "origem=&ultimo_endereco=&forma_pagamento=&video=&url=&evento=&fotos=&sessao=&lista=&perfil_longando=&login_=USER&senha_=123456&logar=Logar");
echo grab_page("http://www.example.com/");?>
```